# How do you set a Regex validation of Email in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

In JSX for ReactJS, I try to make a regex validation on my email field without a dependencie (like Validator), here's what I have for now:

```
isEmailInvalid = ({ email }) => {
        if (email.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    };
```

and some others but none of them worked.. When I search "reactjs regex validation" I obtain very various responses and none of them really worked for me, so I would like to ask:

How do you make a regex validation, without any dependencie, in ReactJS with JSX ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can just `return email.value...` instead of `if (foo) { return true; } else { return false; }` Is the problem you're having with the regex or the React/JSX? If it has to do with the regex but all your React/JSX is working, just remove all that from the question and focus on the regex. If not, please describe what React aspects are failing. Thanks.

Comment: It should be the same as in vanilla JS - just compare the regex against the value of the email prop. JSX essentially just renders HTML tags as React elements. Assuming it's an input, you could just set the input type to email and it will handle the validation for you.

Comment: Thank you for your time ! The problem was that I didn't know how to properly compare the value of my email with the regex above. The **test.(mail)** with the use of the **onChange** method worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On you onChange callback, call this function with the input value.
this function will won't do anything if inputting email has the correct format, but anything goes wrong with format it'll alert of wrong email.

```
<input
 onChange={e => validateEmail(e.target.value)}
/>
```

validation

```
const validateEmail = (mail) => {
 if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(mail))
  {
    return (true)
  }
    alert("You are writing invalid email address!")
    return (false)
}
```

I hope this can be helpful to you.

Comment: Your validation work like a charm, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid writing regex at all cost. While this is not answering how you are able to validate an email using regex, this is how I do it, using validator. First get the package.

```
npm install validator
```

import into project

```
import validator from 'validator';
```

useage

```
let checkIfValidEmail = validator.isEmail(email); // true for good email
```

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I sure it works as I already seen this solution around multiple times. However I wanted to know how to do it without a dependencie before actually using one. My question was not enough specific to exclude Validator and I apologize for that. The question has been updated.